# How do I open OneDrive log (ODL) files?

Tags: windows, logging, onedrive

I am trying to troubleshoot Microsoft OneDrive, in particular I'd like to know which files it has processed.  I found this folder which contains a bunch of ODL files:

C:\Users(user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\logs\Personal

For instance, one filename is SyncEngine-2016-2-16.255.7212.11.odl

How do I open these ODL files?  They appear to be in some binary format.

Comment: Well, from an online search, Microsoft uses .odl as an extension for Object Descriptor Langague files, as part of the COM+/OLE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Here is the Format Definition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ODL's are the glue that combines objects into a library. I can imagine ways that OLE might be involved in a MS synch product, but I have no idea if that is the case.

Comment: I am familiar with Object Descriptor Language files, but this is not one of them.  I ended up with the same result as you when I did a Google search which is why I came here.  The ODL files I am talking about here are in some binary format and have nothing to do with COM.

Comment: @user1042151 any news?

Comment: I'm suspicious that in this case ODL stands for "OneDrive Log". On a whim, I tried to open one in an [SQLite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/), and it recognized it as an encrypted SQLite database. No idea what the password is. Or that could be a total red herring.

Comment: The logs have changed location in macOS Sierra - OneDrive v17.3.6517 Can open *.log but it looks like *.odl are encrypted SQL Lite files /Users/[username]/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac/Data/Library/Logs (And apologies in advance, but not enough credits to comment yet)

Comment: @ElMac no, no idea.

Comment: Visual Studio Express(es) according to this article: http://extension.nirsoft.net/odl

Answer (score 7):

Although ODL files are SQL databases, the OneDrive logs are exclusively for MS tracking and not to the general public.  To enforce that rule, Microsoft encrypted it using a confidential key.  Therefore, it is impossible to open them without knowing the correct key.

Comment: OPs question was about Microsoft OneDrive, not Edge. Your answer very may well be correct, but please edit it to accurately reflect an answer to OPs actual question.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 5):

The OneDrive ODL files are  binary log files stored unencrypted, but obfuscated, and contain detailed debug logs about all actions performed by the OneDrive client. Since the log files are regularly uploaded to Microsoft servers, the obfuscation serves to not see the file names on their side; not to keep the local user from accessing it. The dictionary to un-obfuscate them is available unencrypted on the local disk. Note that the file extensions *are* transferred verbatim.

To access this file, there is an [open source tool](https://github.com/ydkhatri/OneDrive) available. From the same author, there is some [good information](https://www.swiftforensics.com/2022/02/reading-onedrive-logs.html) on how the files are structured, if one is not inclined to read the source.

Comment: This response seems like it should be the accepted answer -- this worked perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @mhud. :)